# second edit fail with Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

I'm  modder of the game Men of war. To create mission, I using Notepad++ for editing the files of the game like the "0.mi" mission file (2000kb) in wich all units of the game are scripted.
I like to use Notepad++ because after turn the langage to C++, I have the possibility to close the unnecessary block files, which is very usefull fonction, and also all the lines are numbered, which allow me to find the bugs in an easy way in case of game crash.
I've got a problem since i passed from XP to Seven: When I open this file for the first time with notepad++ i can edit it (no problem) but my problem is the second time i want to edit this same file, Notepad can't and freeze (not responding). It's seems an issue linked to the "recent file" params inside Notepad++..
The only way i've found to open it again, is to rename the file in .txt for example but sometime i've still the same issue of freezing/noot responding..Heave you any idea on how can I solve this strange issue? (If you want, i can send you a link to this 0.mi file, if you want to analyze this anoying issue)

Comment: Is your file 2MB is size? I would think that Notepad++ is having a problem creating a backup file.

Answer (score -1):

Try free editor **SynWrite**, has no prob to edit 1 files two times, and no interferring should be.